# share variable between Screen class and App class

Tags: kivy

When I run the following scrips it gives the error:ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions. Where did I go wrong?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv ='''
ScreenManager:
    Fscr:
    Sscr:
    
<Fscr>:
    name:'fscr'
    MDTextField:
        id:inp
        hint_text:'File location'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        
    
        
        
        
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text:'To Second Screen'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.3}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='sscr'
            root.manager.screens[1].ids.lbl.text = root.ids.inp.text
           
<Sscr>:
    name:'sscr'
    MDLabel:
        id:lbl
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text:'To First Screen'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.3,'center_y':0.3}
        
        on_press:root.manager.current='fscr'
        '''

class Fscr(Screen):
    pass
class Sscr(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Fscr(name='fscr'))
sm.add_widget(Sscr(name='sscr'))
class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build (self):
        df = root.manager.screens[0].ids.inp.text
        print(df)
        
        
       
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
        
        
MyApp().run()
```

I may be advised as to how to go about this.

Comment: When I tried running your code, instead of the expected `ValueError`, I got an `AttributeError` for the `df = root.manager.screens[0].ids.inp.text` line instead. Are you sure this is the right code that caused `ValueError: App object must be initialized before loading root widget` to be called?

Comment: Yes, my Pal. I got one advice from nice dear, Kxpang. Soon I will implement the suggestion and come back with result. By the by your response is encouraging me to go ahead of my passion to scrpting. Least I can say is "Billion Thanks To You".

Comment: No it was not fruitful. def build (self):
        df = root.manager.screens[0].ids.inp.text
        print(df)

Answer (score 0):

The error has said everything about the problem.

ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget.

You should run the App first before loading any widget to the app.

That said,

```
MyApp().run()
```

should be run first before any calling of kivy widget instances.

`sm = ScreenManager()`

`sm.add_widget(Fscr(name='fscr'))`

`sm.add_widget(Sscr(name='sscr'))`

should come after that.

Comment: Boss, first of all my immense thanks for the response. Since I am away from my machine, I will come back after an hour with success or not, with your advice. Again a billion thanks.